# Parse included file with boost metaparse string

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor, c++17

I want to use boost Metaparse to parse a DSL at compile time.  However for separation concerns, I don't want to write my DSL as one big char into a C++ file, but to use the preprocessor, probably via `#include`, to get the text from a separate file at compile time.

The boost meta parse documentation mentions the preprocessor macro `BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING` so `BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING("DSL content")` translates at preprocessor time to `metaparse::string<'D','S','L',' ', 'c','o'...>`

So instead of

```
using input = BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING("DSL content");
```

I want to use something like

```
using input = BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING(#include "dsl.txt");
```

with dsl.txt containing

```
DSL content
```

but that naive approach won't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible; to `#include` an arbitrary file in a form that can be used directly in a program it is necessary to preprocess the file e.g. by wrapping it in a raw string literal, or using `xxd`.

The (related) papers [P1040](http://wg21.link/p1040) **`std::embed`** and [P1967](http://wg21.link/p1967) **Preprocessor embed** (aka `#embed`) aim to add such a facility to C++ and to the C preprocessor respectively. If the paper is accepted, it could enter the language by C++23. In the interim, https://github.com/ThePhD/embed has patches for gcc and clang; if you are interested in exploring the feature, http://godbolt.org has versions of gcc and clang trunk with the std::embed patches available for online use.

Comment: Thank you, that motivates me, to actually try to go the extra mile and use metaparse, instead of spirit, if their is a realistic chance of a standard way to do this. Will try the gcc and clang patches and the workaround under the other answer for msvc in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adverse to adding a bit of text to your included file, you could make `dsl.txt` be something like:

```
BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING(r"//(
DSL content
)//");
```

And then:

```
using input =
#include "dsl.txt"
```

(That assumes you're using a version of C++ which includes raw strings. Otherwise, it's much more annoying.)

You could add the first and last lines with a simple shell command, if you preferred.

It's not ideal, but since `BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING` seems to require a string literal, I don't think there is a better option.

---

On the other hand, if you find using an external preprocessor acceptable, it is not at all difficult to write one which creates the `metaparse::string` template invocation from a text file. You don't have to limit yourself to the C++ preprocessor. Any build tool will allow you to use a custom build step; even first compiling your preprocessor in order to preprocess the text file.

Comment: Sorry but this is exactly not near any solution. Imagine I want to write a Json scheme parser, which would create the meta stuff at compile time from the json schema file. When I have to add the stuff to the file via a script, while not run the whole json schema parser and transpile a new cpp file, which defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: @superlokkus: up to you what you accept. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure what you mean by "up to you what you accept."?

Comment: @super: I mean you are free to accept an answer or not.

Comment: Got to say combined with cmake configure_file your proposal is nice workaround for MSVC until the proposal @ecatmur mentions is implemented there. +1